# Polars - get hour from Time column

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a Polars df with a column 'Checkout Time' in a string format, e.g '17:54'.

I'm converting to a time format with:
`df = df.with_columns(pl.col('Checkout Time').str.to_time('%H:%M'))`

How would I then get the actual hour of the time as an integer?

I could do it with map_rows but is there a better way than this?

```py
df.with_columns(
    df.select('Checkout Time').map_rows(lambda x: x[0].hour)
).rename({'map': 'Hour'})
```

But this seems annoying, is there a way to do it directly in with_columns?

Some example data:

```py
data = np.array(['06:30', '17:45', '18:32'])
df = pl.from_numpy(data, schema=["Checkout Time"])
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('Checkout Time').str.to_time('%H:%M'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`polars.Expr.dt.hour`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.hour.html) directly:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np


data = np.array(['06:30', '17:45', '18:32'])
df = pl.from_numpy(data, schema=["Checkout Time"])
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('Checkout Time').str.to_time('%H:%M'))

df = df.with_columns(Hour=pl.col('Checkout Time').dt.hour())
```

> ```
> >>> df
> shape: (3, 2)
> ┌───────────────┬──────┐
> │ Checkout Time ┆ Hour │
> │ ---           ┆ ---  │
> │ time          ┆ i8   │
> ╞═══════════════╪══════╡
> │ 06:30:00      ┆ 6    │
> │ 17:45:00      ┆ 17   │
> │ 18:32:00      ┆ 18   │
> └───────────────┴──────┘
> ```